# Iteration through a Saxon-JS sequence

Tags: javascript, saxon-js

This javascript (hosted on a browser console) ...

```
var xmlDoc = jQuery.parseXML("<foo>Stuff</foo>");
for (let item of SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate( '/foo/text()', xmlDoc,
                 {resultForm:'iterator'})) {console.log(item);}
```

... returns error ...

```
SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

... instead of the expected output ...

```
"Stuff"
```

**Why?**

According to [documentation here](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!api/xpathEvaluate), the evaluate() expression should return an iterator. But it does not.

Libraries used include:

1. jQuery; and
2. [Saxon-js](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!about) javascript library.

---

### Update

I can get a functionally correct result with this alternative expression ...

```
for (let item of SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('string(foo/text())',xmlDoc, 
  {resultForm:'array'})) {console.log(item)}
```

... but I really want to use a lazy iterator, if that is possible, rather than an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I am just invoking iterator wrong. This works ...

```
SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate( '/foo/text()', xmlDoc,
  {resultForm:'iterator'}).forEachItem( function( node){
    console.log( node)})
```